# launchd sets wrong user

Tags: macos, launchd

I'm currently working with LaunchDaemons and I have the problem, that launchd apparently uses the wrong user.

Here's the plist of my LaunchDaemon (file name is org.test.user.plist):

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.test.user</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>/Users/Shared/test_user.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>_postgres</string>
    <key>Umask</key>
    <integer>000</integer>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Shared/test_user.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/Shared/test_user.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This LaunchDaemon simply executes the script 'test_user.sh'. This is the content of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

postbat=/Users/Shared/BatScope4/pgdc/postbat_v1_0

echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'):"
echo "user: $USER"
echo "id: $(id)"
echo "umask: $(umask)"
echo "$postbat:"
ls -Al "$postbat"

exit 0
```

After loading the LaunchDaemon from the bash with

```
sudo launchctl load -F org.test.user.plist
```

the log file test_user.log contains the following:

```
2015-03-13 11:19:32:
user: _postgres
id: uid=216(_batscope) gid=216(_postgres) groups=216(_postgres),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),402(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),408(com.apple.sharepoint.group.7),409(com.apple.sharepoint.group.8),403(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),100(_lpoperator),401(com.apple.sharepoint.group.4),405(com.apple.sharepoint.group.6),404(com.apple.sharepoint.group.3),406(com.apple.sharepoint.group.5)
umask: 0000
/Users/Shared/BatScope4/pgdc/postbat_v1_0:
ls: postbat_v1_0: Permission denied
```

What you need to know is, that once the user (and the group) _postgres existed with a UID=216. BUT, I deleted it and set-up a new user _postgres which has the following properties:

```
PrimaryGroupID: 223
RecordName: _postgres
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Users
UniqueID: 223
UserShell: /bin/bash
```

Does anybody know, why launchd keeps using the old user _postgres and how I can force it not to?

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of research and trial I found what caused launchd to set the wrong user.

In the file /etc/master.passwd there was a line generated by the old _postgres user. I got rid of this line using

```
sudo sed -i '' '/^_postgres.*$/d' /etc/master.passwd
```

and now launchd picks the right user.

So if you delete a user using

```
sudo dscl . delete /Users/username
```

the entries of this user in the passwd files are not deleted. One has to do that manually to ensure there is no mix-up of users when.